# freeware HTML creating tools for Linux

Tags: html, linux, centos

I have linux centos 5.3. I am in progress to create a website but i am not aware of writing HTML. I need some tool to convert text to html. On google I have found many tools with can help in creating html pages but all are for windows. Can anyone please suggest me any similar tool for linux system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Nvu](http://net2.com/nvu/) is/was the closesd thing to a WYSIWYG type of HTML editor on linux for a long time, now there is also [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/). There used to be a Mozilla web editor, but I don't think it is still available.

But try to [teach yourself at least some HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/Html/default.asp), the basics are not hard and it is useful knowledge even if you don't plan to type a lot of it.

Answer (score 3):

i **really** recommend you learn HTML if you want to write web pages.

if you want to convert text to simple HTML there are some other markup languages, e.g. [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a perl script which i found from [FTLS.org](http://ftls.org/en/examples/perl-tools/txt2html.shtml). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be stating the obvious, but I think it's still useful to point out that HTML files **ARE** text files.

So [Octopus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146250/octopus) is providing a link to a useful Perl script which replaces certain characters with HTML entities and allows text to be surrounded by <PRE> tags. This will be useful if your HTML pages are mostly text.

And [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) suggests you learn HTML. I tend to agree, because then you can create HTML with any text editor.

But [eLZahR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159218/elzahr) proposes an HTML editor with WYSIWYG features, if you can find one, to make it a little easier.

The choice is yours. Once again, learn HTML. Don't rely entirely on fancy frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

Yo can use an WYSIWYG editor like Dreamweaver, or a content manager like Wordpress.
Check these lists (verify that they are compatible with your SO):

[HTML Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_content_management_systems#Free_and_open_source_software) (Get all which have a WYSIWYG editor and a free/open-source license). I would recommend you Kompozer.

[Content Management Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_content_management_systems#Free_and_open_source_software) (Get just the free ones).
I think it's the better option because the html editors aren't very useful when you have a minimum quantity of information.

ANYWAY I would encourage you to learn HTML. It's very very easy and it will help you a lot.

Comment: I was just giving an idea of the software he was looking for. Kompozer an Nvu are Dreamweaver-like programs, but DW is ver much famous. You can see that the user who made the question has marked as correct answer one which recommends Nvu an Kompozer, the same as mine.
Thank you for the downvote, though.